# About csc.exe, is it necessary to learn?

Tags: compiler-construction, c#-3.0, types, csc, clr4.0

I am an intermediate programmer and these days I've been analyzing the CLR, my question is what is the need to learn all the commands of c# command line! It's so boring.

is it necessary?

Comment: No, you don't need to learn anything, there's csc /help available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find, as I did, that sometimes it's just easier to start up Notepad (or your favorite text editor) to create a simple C# program.  Then use the command line tool to compile it quickly, without having to go to the trouble of starting Visual Studio, building a project, etc.  It's a whole lot easier and faster to just type:

`csc /t:exe MyProgram.cs`

Knowledge is rarely useless. Some of the things you consider 'boring' turn out to be the most important and eventually the most interesting.

In the case of the .NET command line tools, I would suggest learning about them--what tools exist, what they do, and how to operate them--but I wouldn't say that you need to become a command line guru.

Comment: I ask because I'm reading "CLR via C # " and noticed a particular importance for a series of commands. Thanks!

Comment: @Diego - That is one of my favourite books. I have upvoted this answre because of what said about boring stuff turning out to be important.  I personally think that the compiler would be one of the most important things to know about?  I don't mean memorising the syntax.  But knowing what it can and can't do is surely hugely relevant?

Answer (score 1):

It depends a lot on how you plan to use C#. If you're building things only from Visual Studio or another IDE, it's probably less of a priority. However, if you'll be building C# projects using other tools (ant, for example), you should familiarize yourself with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a tool like Visual Studio, you can most probably get away without learning command line compilation. However, knowing them would be of advantage in situations when you don't have advance IDE.

This goes for every language and not just c#.